# Working with DjVu with .NET

Tags: c#, djvu

I need to open DjVu files in my program, so I'm looking for some library. It must be free library, opensource would be better. When I tried to google it, I found only links to some books about .Net in *djvu format :D

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but I wanted to include that I just uploaded a fully managed Djvu reader written in C#. If you make improvements please share. https://github.com/Telavian/DjvuNet

Comment: continued by https://github.com/DjvuNet/DjvuNet

Answer (score 0):

The following techniques may be useful.

First technique:

1) http://javadjvu.foxtrottechnologies.com/ djvu support for java

2) use ikvm.net to convert java code in dot net

it is tedious but can be tried and i think best method

Second technique:

http://twit88.com/blog/2009/02/28/open-source-windows-djvu-viewer/
a viewer to open djvu files

for more detail go through

sourceforge djvu

you can get basic details from here

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the Java solutions, but... They are JAVA %) It's better to me to use C++ variants...